# How mui react website is adding inline style to navbar (header) padding right 33px when clicking on select menu , modal?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

Does MUI React have a built-in mechanism for dynamically adding inline styles to components based on user interaction?

Navbar is flickering when select option is clicked

I can add class to body when select option is clicked , for an individual page, but can we do it globally for all select option?

[View Mui React page](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/)